# Select big data with RODBC from SQL Server is slow

Tags: rodbc

I use sqlQuery in RODBC to select data from a SQL Server database, the data is about 2000000 rows and 130 columns, and it takes more than 30 minutes. However in SQL Server Management Studio, it only needs 2 minutes.

How can I speed up the data select or should I use other packages but not RODBC?

Comment: I have a similar problem, task takes 10 seconds in SQL but 60 seconds using RODBC. I *thought* this is was due to the time it takes RODBC to open the connection but your 30 mins makes me suspect otherwise.

Comment: i've had similar issue. it was resolved with RJDBC, however, it means all data is read in as either character or numeric. i had a date/time stamp which was turned to character which was not ideal. RODBC performance was fixed in this scenario when i set Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT') - same time zone as SQL server - before running sqlQuery, it ensured that data was read in as required. RODBC performance currently however is very uncertain, it works on occasion but not other times. it would be great to get some clarity why.